# Rails 3 - downloading large amounts of picture from the web

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, file, download

I am solving the question about downloading a large amounts of picture from the web. I have XML file with links to images on web sites and I have to download this images. Every image have ca ±3MB and the count of images is tens of thousands, so is not possible to store these images on hosting (100.000 x 3MB)...

And these images I need to display on sites. I don't worked yet with so large amounts of data yet, so I would like to ask you, what could be the best idea for displaying these images on "my" page.

My first ideas:
- store only links into my database table and then for displaying images use just **image_tag URL_OF_IMAGE**
- some a way of caching images/links of images (I don't know specifically)

Can you help me, please, what you think will be the fastest way for displaying images from foreigners sources?

Thank you in advance,
M.

Comment: Do you have licensing rights to the images? If so, does the host have a hot-linking policy?

Comment: Of course I have. But the access to the images is only through XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), but as ezkl says, make sure you have licensing rights to the images or you'll land yourself in trouble (and in any case it is wrong to use the content without permission).

Comment: As I wrote above, I have the permission to images. Amazaon S3 could be fine, thanks for help